# Lambda sort in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

I'm trying to convert code from Python 2.x to 3.x from [here](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/09/30/colour-sorting/) as and have stumbled over a syntax error with Lambda.

```
colours.sort(key=lambda (r,g,b): step(r,g,b,8)) # invalid syntax
```

I assumed that the parentheses before the colon are not needed

```
colours.sort(key=lambda r,g,b: step(r,g,b,8))
```

Only that results in a TypeError: () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'g' and 'b'

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuple unpacking in lambda arguments was removed in Python 3.

You'll need to manually index into the tuple.

```
colours.sort(key=lambda rgb: step(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],8))
```

Comment: Yes. That makes sense now. Thank you.